# How to declare a Map type in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to declare a type like this:

```
interface DependData {[key: string]: string};
```

but with error like this:

```
Statements are not allowed in ambient contexts
```

Comment: Its an object declaration not a Map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: In case someone stumbled on this answer looking for [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) Data Structure in JS, you can specify types for key-value pairs as : `let m = new Map<type1, type2>();`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The error message you are describing occurs in a declaration file.

To make this work, you need remove the semi-colon at the end of your interface declaration:

```
interface DependData {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

The extra semi-colon is causing an [empty statement to be parsed](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQA4RAE1XMOZAbwG0BrCATwC5kBnMKUAcwF07HmQWBfAbiA) in addition to the interface declaration, thus giving that error message.

Comment: Also, for those who needs enum for the key, `[key in YourEnumType]` syntax should help. Cheers

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't work for me. Unable to instantiate the map. It set un interface named StringNumberKVP with [key: string]: boolean. I try to instantiate a map. The pre-compiler returns: Type 'Map<string, number>' is not assignable to type 'StringNumberKVP'. Index signature is missing in type 'Map<string, number>'.

Comment: The above would be created like so: `const data: DependData = {};` (note the question above is technically asking why they're having trouble declaring an index access type)

Comment: @Luc-Olivier That's a different problem. You know the type of `Map<string, number>`, because you just said it. This question is for when you are using an `Object` (like from `{ these: 'literals' }` and its properties as a map. You can tell typescript the type of every property, no matter what the property name.

Comment: @doug65536 got it. Thanks

Comment: With this approach, you can't replace the `key: string` with any other type. The compiler will complain.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not good at typescript, and when I dig into our codebase, i found the following approach is also valid, and can be more robust, because otherwise you won't be able to use non-string as keys.

```
export enum SORT_TYPES {
  DISPLAY_NAME_ASC = 'Patient: A-Z',
  DISPLAY_NAME_DESC = 'Patient: Z-A',
}

export const SORT_ORDERS: Map<SORT_TYPES, String[]> = new Map([
  [SORT_TYPES.DISPLAY_NAME_ASC, ['display_name', 'ASC']],
  [SORT_TYPES.DISPLAY_NAME_DESC, ['display_name', 'DESC']],
])
```

So here a `Map` type is used, and the key type becomes `SORT_TYPES` instead of a string.

Comment: Thank you. This is a better answer because otherwise functions such as .get(...) are not properly detected by the compiler.